# jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, prolog, jpl

I am using java netbeans and want to use prolog api in it but i keep getting error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at contacteditor.Advisory.<init>(Advisory.java:18)
at contacteditor.ContactEditor.main(ContactEditor.java:21)
```

Can anyone help me out please ?

Comment: Well, it can't find dependent libraries. Try running a tool dependency walker on jpl.dll. It will tell you what libraries are missing.

Comment: but i couldn't get those libraries

Comment: Well then you should. The error is clearly telling you it's expecting either this file C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\jpl.dll or dependencies of that file. If you don't have it there probably you didn't install what you needed.

Comment: One quick and dirty fix might simply be to append `C:\Program Files\swipl\bin` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Comment: it's 2020 and now I face this problem and can't seem to figure it out.