# Error trying to install jpl library. jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, prolog, swi-prolog

I have a problem installing **jpl** library. I installed the latest **swipl** version (but I tried also unstable versions before):

```
SWI-Prolog 7.2.3 for Windows 7/8/10 64-bit edition
```

Then I added dependent paths to environment variables:

```
Variable: SWI_HOME_DIR 
Value: C:\Program Files\swipl
```

Then I added, to `Path` these values:

```
%SWI_HOME_DIR%\lib\jpl.jar;
%SWI_HOME_DIR%\lib;
%SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin
```

I also added the VM argument like this:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\swipl\bin"
```

to make sure that Eclipse sees this folder.

After that I still get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\swipl\bin\jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1855)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.jpl7.JPL.loadNativeLibrary(JPL.java:79)
    at org.jpl7.fli.Prolog.<clinit>(Prolog.java:41)
    at org.jpl7.Query.open(Query.java:260)
    at org.jpl7.Util.textToTerm(Util.java:102)
    at org.jpl7.Query.Query1(Query.java:129)
    at org.jpl7.Query.<init>(Query.java:120)
```

I'm 100% sure, that Eclipse sees that `jpl.dll` file, but in my opinion, it seems that it needs some other libraries.

I know that this thread is probably duplicate of either of these:

[jpl.dll: Can't find dependent libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924081/jpl-dll-cant-find-dependent-libraries)
[JPL Can't find dependent libraries of jpl.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913232/jpl-cant-find-dependent-libraries-of-jpl-dll)

but these questions are not answered or the answers doesn't helps in my case.

Comment: I try run `swipl` sample using the setting of this question, but I cannot reproduce the error.
Do you get similar error when you try to execute the program from command line? 
If yes, you should make sure all required DLL available using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com)

Answer (score 0):

> I added dependent paths to environment variables:
>   Variable: `SWI_HOME_DIR`
>
> Value: `C:\Program Files\swipl`
>
> Then I added, to `Path` these values:
>
> `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\lib\jpl.jar;`
>   `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\lib;`
>
> `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin`

## This is the installation instructions:

Put the three *library files* (`jpl.dll`, `jpl.jar` and `jpl.pl`) where each can be found:

- `jpl.dll` must be found by the **Windows kernel**, and can go in any
  folder on your **PATH**          *environment variable*; 
  perhaps `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\bin`
  or your *Windows system folder*
- `jpl.jar` must be found by any **Java VM**'s (and compilers) used
  with **JPL**. One possibility is to put it on your global **CLASSPATH**.
- `jpl.pl` is a **Prolog** source module, and must be found by any
  **SWI-Prolog** engines used with **JPL**: 
  I suggest putting it in `%SWI_HOME_DIR%\library` and then invoking
  `make_library_index/1` on that folder (see a **SWI-Prolog** manual
  for details) so that the autoloader can find it.